# response 422 after trying to send post request with json file

Tags: python, json, api, post

I have been trying to find an answer that work on my case but had no success.

I am getting a response 422 when running the code below. I have replaced the json in the response variable and also used json.dumps around the data variable but I am still getting this response. Would you be able to find the issue within my json file? Thanks a lot

```
todaystr = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today = datetime.strptime(todaystr, '%Y-%m-%d')
first_day_of_month = today.replace(day=1)
day_count_str = today - first_day_of_month
day_count_int = day_count_str / timedelta(days=1)
day_count_split = str(day_count_int)
sep = '.'
day_count = day_count_split.split(sep, 1)[0]
dt = str(first_day_of_month.timestamp())




data = {"requestId": "numberOfUniqueAccountsAndVisitors", "timeSeries": {"period": "dayRange", "count": day_count, "first": dt}, "source": {"events": None}, "pipeline": [{"reduce": [{"reduce": {"visitors": {"count": "visitorId"}, "accounts": {"count": "accountId"}}}]}]}
 
headers = {
      'x-pendo-integration-key': API_Key,
      'content-type': "application/json"
}
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(response)
response_dictionary = json.loads(response.content)
print(response_dictionary)
```

Comment: 422 would be a validation failure of some kind but without seeing the API docs nobody can conclusively say what the problem is. I will say, `None` is not valid in json, it would have to be null.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The API example has null instead, however, when I put null I get an error that this variable is no defined. Thanks in advance

Comment: Python dictionary is not JSON. You need to parse your data into valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also parsed using json.dumps in the data variable but now I am getting the following error: 
<Response [400]>
{'overall': {'DeserializationError': 'json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type api.aggregationApiRequest'}, 'fields': {'pipeline': 'Required'}}
Any idea whatelse I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the payload to the Pendo Aggregation API, the request object should not be an array. And make sure the "key" should be named as "request"(singular), not as "requests"(plural).
Try something like this

```
{
  "response": {
    "mimeType": "application/json"
  },
  "request": {
    "name": "accounts-last7days",
    "requestId": "accounts-last7days"
  }
}
```